# Stripe - Immediately charging

Tags: php, reactjs, stripe-payments

I want create a charge without a confirmation on the front end. That means that a customer fills out the card details via React's `CardElement` and then should click on a booking button. Is this possible without a confirm page to confirm the payment intend? The confirmation should work automatically?

I have implemented `$stripe->charges->create(...)` in PHP, but this did not work.

I'm using React & PHP on server side.

Comment: What you mean exactly by creating a charge without a confirmation ? are you looking for collecting the payment method on the frontend and then create the charge using that collected Payment Method on your backend ? if so you can use SetupIntent: this guide is a good start:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#charge-saved-payment-method